# How do I join a list of values into a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, join, ipython

I am trying to join a list to a dictionary in Python 3 and return the sum of the key values.

So far, I can't join the two, I've tried using `get` and `set` and am not succeeding.

I also tried a for loop with set linking listy and dict2, like this:

```
dict2 = {
1: "A",
2: "B",
3: "C"
}

listy = ['A', 'M', 'B', 'A']

for k in dict2:
    if set(listy) & set(dict2[value]):
        print(dict2.key)
```

This is the error I'm getting in IPython:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-291-5a5e2eb8d7f8> in <module>
     10 
     11 for k in dict2:
---> 12     if set(listy) & set(dict2[value]):
     13         print(dict2.key)
     14 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I would expect the output to be
A
B
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task will be easier if you flip the keys and values in your dictionary. I assume that there are no duplicate values.

```
dict2 = {1: "A", 2: "B", 3: "C"}
lookup = {value: key for key, value in dict2.items()}
```

Now `lookup` is `{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}`.
Now you can loop over the list:

```
listy = ['A', 'M', 'B', 'A']
result = []
for key in listy:
    if key in lookup:
        result.append(key)
```

Now `result` is `['A', 'B', 'A']`. The code will be shorter with a list comprehension:

```
result = [key for key in listy if key in lookup]
```

As far as I unterstood the question you want to get the sum of the keys in `dict2` for every entry in `listy` that has a corresponding value in `dict2`. If you have created the `lookup`dictionary you can do the following to get the single values.

```
[lookup.get(key, 0) for key in listy]
# -> [1, 0, 2, 1]
```

If a key doesn't appear in the dictionary it gets a default value of `0`.

To get the sum is easy now

```
sum(lookup.get(key, 0) for key in listy)
# -> 4
```

Comment: Thank you! I had it that way the first time and will happily switch it back.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list-comprehension:

```
[x for x in listy if x in set(dict2.values())]
```

**In code**:

```
dict2 = {
1: "A",
2: "B",
3: "C"
}

listy = ['A', 'M', 'B', 'A']

print([x for x in listy if x in set(dict2.values())])
# ['A', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use `dict[k]` instead of `dict2[value]`

Also your dictionary's entries contain single values (not lists) so you can use the `in` operator:

for example:

```
 # if listy is a dictionary or a small list, you don't need to build a set 

 for key,value in dict2.items():
    if value in listy:
        print(key)
```

or :

```
 # If listy is a large list, you should build a set only once 

 listySet = set(listy)
 for key,value in dict2.items():
    if value in listySet:
        print(key)
```

If you have a lot of code to perform on the "joined" data, you could structure the condition like this:

```
 for key,value in dict2.items():
    if value not in listy: continue
    print(key)
    ... do more stuff ...
```

If you're only looking for a sum, you can do it more directly:

```
# counting sum of dict2 keys matching each value in listy  
# select sum(dict2.key) from listy join dict2 where dict2.value = listy.value
# (note that an inverted dict2 would be better suited for that)

result = sum(key*listy.count(value) for key,value in dict2.items())

# counting sum of keys in dict2 that have a value in listy 
# select sum(dict2.key) from dict2 where exists listy.value = dict2.value

result = sum(key for key,value in dict2.items() if value in listy)
```

In short, you have to implement the linking logic that the RDBMS query optimizer normally does for you in SQL.

Comment: Thank you!

For the future, is the best way to "join" to a dictionary -- with an "in" statement?

I'm so accustomed to joining tables in SQL this feels inefficient.

Comment: You could use the `keys` and `values` methods to get a list of the keys/values of that dictionary then you can use the `+` symbol to join that array with another array.

Comment: This will actually just print `['B', 'A']`

Comment: When working in memory, the I/O constraints of databases don't apply.  Direct memory access is essentially free, as opposed to query costs entailed by joins in SQL.  It's a different way of thinking about performance.

Comment: Changed the set & set code which was returning values instead of keys (my bad).